# Very unreasonable use of CPU by system

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, kernel

Im quite new to mac enviroment, but been on Ubuntu for years..
Thing is, till last week everything seemed smooth and nice, i was ready to sign on to "apple just works" mentality, but then something happend.

To my knowledge there has not been any changes in connected hardware, same mouse, same 4k monitor etc..

But since last week, my mac has been ultra slow to the point that there HAS TO BE something wrong here.. for example, loading up this stackExchange page took close to 3min, and now while i'm writing, it's like watching a slideshow.. and this is less than 5min after boot.

I would suspect malmware, but then again, im not the most familiar with this OS. But even with that, my computer is quite heavily monitored for stuff like this. and i have experience of dealing with our security support, i know for a fact that they DO act fast if there is actual problem found.

That kernel task is pretty goddamn **suspicious** tho?!?

For other solutions, i tried to change from Firefox to Chrome and kill all unused processes to no avail.

also kernel_task has not come down from that level while writing this.

[image: That kernel task tho?]

[image]

Comment: Basically, kernel_task artificially ramps up to try cool the Mac. kernel_task is essentially the very 'root' of the entire OS.

Comment: Agreed. When a Mac overheats, it throttles back the CPU to keep its temperature from reaching potentially damaging levels. The throttling is counted as time spent in `kernel_task` (even though it's not actually spent _running_ `kernel_task`), and so lots of time shown there is a strong indicator of overheating. — And a common cause of that is dust and debris around the fans. If you can't open the machine up, you could try blowing hard in all the air holes (e.g. with a mini-vac or compressed air can) to try to dislodge some of it.